# asm/ioctl.h is missing on my gumstix linux image

Tags: linux, embedded, gumstix

I am trying to include `ioctl.h` on my Gumstix Linux in order to use the on-board ADC.

In turn, `ioctl.h` includes `asm/ioctls.h` which is missing on my machine.

In fact, the entire `/usr/asm` directory is missing. Does anybody know how I am supposed to add/install it and why it is missing?

Comment: Sanity check: you did check `/usr/include/asm`, not `/usr/asm`, right? I don't know the Gumstix development kit; the `asm` directory is for applications that interact closely with the kernel (it's from the kernel, not from libc) so it may be in a separate component from the usual headers.

Comment: P.S. to people who want to migrate this to SU: no! This question is about development tools, so it's on-topic on SO. And it would be off-topic on SU, a Gumstix board isn't a computer by its definition.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  I created a symbolic link for this directory, as well as several others (sorry I cannot be more specific as this was at a previous employer and I don't have it with me.)

Make sure you have installed the kernel headers:

> opkg install task-native-sdk

Then create symbolic links:

> ln -s /usr/asm /usr/src/linux-3.0.0/include/asm/

(again, going on memory...)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on architecture. For example for x86, the file

/arch/x86/include/asm/ioctl.h

includes

include/asm-generic/ioctl.h

that contains the relevant information